# Can I register components with React like code and get it back using A-frame?

Tags: components, aframe

Is it possible to create a component like pseudo code below using A-frame? I'm not using React/Babel at all inside my project, but I like the syntax of React/Babel.

```jsx
AFRAME.registerComponent('myComponent', {
    init: function () {
        this.location;

        return (
            <a-entity location={this.location}>
                <a-image src="./1.png" />
                <a-image src="./2.png" />
            </a-entity>
        );
    }
});
```

I would reuse this component using pseude code below:

```js
var comp = document.querySelector('a-scene').components.myComponent;
comp.location = `${Math.random() * 10} ${Math.random() * 10} ${Math.random() * 10}`;
document.querySelector('a-scene').appendChild(comp);
```

Answer (score 3):

There actually is something similar to this, you can use the template component in KFrame (by Kevin Ngo, the developer of A-Frame). It supports multiple template styles and string interpolation!
[A-Frame template component](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/template)

The examples indexed on this repo should be selfexplainatory.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use JSX without React (but with Babel) to create elements since it translates the calls to `createElement`. I haven't tried though, but just a possibility.

```
this.el.appendChild(
  <a-entity>
    <a-box></a-box>
  </a-entity>
);
```